# Python HTTServer: Connection Refused

Tags: python, python-3.x, http

I am trying to upload a few files to my Unix system from my Windows desktop. Now previously, I used the python's HTTP server and it worked like a charm. But after moving to my new desktop when I run the command I get something like:

```
H:\apache-tomcat-9.0.30\bin>python -m http.server 9000
Serving HTTP on :: port 9000 (http://[::]:9000/) ...
```

Somehow I don't see the hostname in the middle of the `[]`. Shouldn't it be:

```
Serving HTTP on :: port 9000 (http://0.0.0.0:9000/) ...
```

or something on those lines?

I still try to fetch a few file on Unix system using `wget` but I keep getting `Connection Refused` error. Previously I used 3.7.2 of Python now I am on 3.8.1.

Comment: `::` is the IPv6 equivalent of `0.0.0.0` in IPv4.

Comment: Force binding ipv4 localhost: `python -m http.server 9000 --bind 127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Oh... That didn't even cross my mind!

Comment: @MauriceMeyer. Okay. Let me give that a try and report back. Thanks!

Comment: @MauriceMeyer. Thanks. That worked. But can you please tell me why its failing in the first place. You can make it the answer, I will mark it resolved.